# "array-contains" firebase v9 query giving me an error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am using Sonny Sangha's Whatsapp Clone video (he is using firebase v8 whereas I am using firebase v9)

The code below checks if the input you type in is already present in the Firestore Database, and if this is true, then we alert the user with a message that the user you are trying to chat with already exists. Otherwise, it will create a document in Firestore with the user email and the input you typed (the person you want to chat with).

```
const chatAlreadyExists = (recipientEmail) => {
// I used "!!" to convert this into boolean
!!chatsSnapshot?.docs.find(
  (chat) => chat.data().users.find((user) => user === 
  recipientEmail)?.length > 0
 );
};
const input = prompt(
  "Please enter an email address for the user you wish to chat 
   with"
);

if (
  EmailValidator.validate(input) &&
  !chatAlreadyExists(input) &&
  input !== user.email
) {

  const payload = {
    users: [user.email, input],
  };
  addDoc(collectionRef, payload);
```

The chatsSnapshot is a real-time listener to the Firestore database

```
 const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "chats");
  const userChatRef = query(
    collectionRef,
    where("users", "array-contains", user.email)
  );
```

const [chatsSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);

Comment: What is the error message you get? And where exactly does it appear?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error message after refreshing, the code just doesn't do what I indend for it to do.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question then, as "giving me an error" is likely leading more folks than just me to expect an error message. --- While you're editing please also add a screenshot of a document you'd expect to be returned, and show that you can reproduce the problem with that document and a hard-coded value for `user.email` (since we can't see your `user`). --- I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains a lot more information that makes it more likely that someone here can help.